# Is it safe to visit Amsterdam on New Year's?

Tags: international-travel, netherlands

I planned to travel from Italy to Amsterdam to celebrate New Year's eve.
I was told that the zone of Europe I'm gonna visit is at high risk of terrorism attack.

Am I encountering problems / risks travelling to that area of the Europe?

Comment: Is there a particular fear you have that makes you think it wouldn't be?

Comment: Please define what counts as "safe" to you (and possibly what your alternatives are). What risks are you especially concerned about? Because there are risks with visiting anywhere, but they may well be lower than you normally experience.

Comment: There's some threat of pick pocketing but nothing worse than any other city in the west.

Comment: I was referring to terrorism risk as that is a high risk area, as far as I know

Comment: @Phate01 please edit your question to clarify that - also either: tell us what levels of risk you find acceptable or rephrase the question to ask about the relative risk. "Safe" alone is a value judgement, and one we cannot make for you. Also, where you are from would be ueful (if not necessary) information. It can help us quantify the risks relevant to the ones you normally face.

Comment: @user568458: I was a bit concerned because the ones of the France attacks were all coming from Belgium

Comment: @CMaster I edited my question

Comment: @Phate01 Netherlands and Belgium are very different. Also, fireworks are a real and serious hazard on New Year in Amsterdam, I believe there are accidents every year.

Comment: Accidents with fireworks are mostly kids and some men who are not careful when setting off fireworks, often when building bigger bangs. But every so often we hear that onlookers got some fireworks exploding in their face. And as there will be fireworks everywere in the city all evening into the night, (6 PM to 2 AM according to the rules but in actuality much longer.)

Comment: @user568458: note that the Netherlands already is part of the air strikes on IS, but only in Iraq, not over the border in Syria. But anyway, although there is a chance that maybe some day there will be a terrorist attack somewhere in the Netherlands is not a reason not to come here.

Answer (score 5):

You don't say where you are from, so I will cite a few countries advice. The [UK's Foreign and Commonwealth office notes only](https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/netherlands) a "general risk of terrorism" - about as low as you get - and the [US state department currently has no alerts or warnings](http://travel.state.gov/content/passports/en/alertswarnings.html) for the Netherlands. Of course, terrorism is by its nature difficult to predict, but the agencies that would be expected to know and be concerned do not appear to be advising against travel to the Netherlands in any way.

It is important to put the risks from terrorism in perspective. In almost all countries save for a few exceedingly violent ones, traffic incidents are the principal cause of violent deaths (as we discussed on another question, despite all the attention of the Paris attacks, the amount of people who died there was equivalent to 10-12 days of French road casualties). In this respect, [Wikipedia places the Netherlands as having the 13th lowest road deaths per capita](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_traffic-related_death_rate) with only 3.9 deaths per 100000, considerably lower than say the USA at 11.6, Australia at 5.6 or Russia at 18.6. These data do not look at how many of these fatalities are tourists however.  Beyond even that, Amsterdam has relativley little road traffic (at least in the central, touristy areas). It does however have many canals, which the UK's FCO notes several tourists drown in each year, normally while intoxicated. Try to avoid this.

While it's of lower concern, you may also be pleased to know that the [Netherlands reports a low intentional homicide rate of 0.9 per 100000](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_intentional_homicide_rate), again ranking well against most of the world - although one might anticipate that a more of those crimes are concentrated in a major city like Amsterdam then in the rural regions of the country.

Comment: I'm from Italy as I wrote at the beginning of the question by the way

Comment: @Phate01 Sorry, missed that. Does the Italian government provide any travel advice? Might be worth looking at, I'd struggle to know what it is saying however. Anyway, given the statistics I talked about above, I wouldn't especially worry about terrorism in the Netherlands - you're probably safer there than you are at home.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the FCO travel advice has a terrorism warning on *literally every* country. I believe "general risk" is the second lowest level, above "low risk" (countries like Iceland, Swaziland, Bolivia, Fiji...). Sweden and Italy are examples of other "general threat" countries. France and Belgium are rated "high threat".

Answer (score 0):

As I was told, the threat level for the Netherlands is mantained as substantial, as explained [in this article](https://english.nctv.nl/themes_en/Counterterrorism/terrorist_threat_assessment_netherlands/current_threat_level/).

There states:

> The threat level for the Netherlands has again been maintained at
>   ‘substantial’. This means that there is a real chance of an attack in
>   the Netherlands.[...]

Also the nl Times states that the is a concrete risk in the country, as explained in this [article](http://www.nltimes.nl/2014/09/24/netherlands-terrorism-threat-substantial/).

Even the guardian has its says: http://www.theguardian.com/world/2015/jan/16/terror-threat-jihadis-five-countries

Comment: Um, yeah, the USA [also decided the whole world was worth a travel alert](http://www.wcvb.com/news/state-department-issues-worldwide-travel-alert/36619982), but if you travel, you'll find for the most part, the world and people in it are safe.  State departments and media have to over-hype it, or if something rare does happen people will complain they weren't warned.
Yes there's a heightened risk of something happening in Amsterdam compared with normal, but it's still very low.  You're still more likely to die in a car crash than by terrorism.

Comment: You've also cherry picked artlcles of doom and gloom, while the other answer cites state departments and other sources. Consider where you get your facts from, and the old media adage that 'if it bleeds, it leads'.

Comment: You're from Italy, right? [Italy recently raised it's terrorism alert level](http://www.thelocal.it/20151114/italy-raises-terror-alert-after-paris-attacks), to ["highest possible in the absence of a direct attack"](http://www.nbcnews.com/storyline/paris-terror-attacks/italy-tourist-sites-are-potential-targets-state-department-n466091). But I assume you don't put on a flak jacket before you go to the shops. I see no reason to think the Netherlands is at a *higher* risk than Italy.

Comment: Eh I wouldn't take that too seriously.
The UK's Terror threat level has been at the second highest level for pretty much the last 10 years or so, but there has been no significant terrorist attacks. I think it just lets the authorities use various powers as they seem necessary.

Comment: @CMaster you're right, there's no need to worry about